# C Function call with *param and &param

Tags: c, pointers

I have seen C function calls that deal with *param1 and &param2

```
   func1(*param1);

   func2(&param2);
```

I know the * and & has to with pointers. So what's purpose doing with these two different ways?  Any advantage of each one?

Answer (score 7):

```
func1(*param1);
```

In this case, you are passing the contents of the address to which the pointer `param1` points to the function `func1`.

```
func2(&param2);
```

In this case, you are passing the address of `param2` to the function `func2`.

In essence, the second creates a new pointer (i.e., "look over there!") and the first tells you what the pointer is pointing at (i.e., "what's in this box?").

To drive the point home, here is a practically useless example:

```
int x = 1234; /* an example value */
int *y = &x; /* The pointer y now points at x (or the memory location in which x resides). */
int z = *y; /* z is now = 1234 - it looked at what y was pointing at and took that value. */
int w = *(&x); /* w is now = 1234 - I created a temporary pointer and then immediately dereferenced it. */
```

Also, note that `int *y` pointer definition: the star has a different meaning during variable definitions.  It is used to define a pointer rather than dereference one.  A bit confusing for a novice admittedly....

Comment: @KenoguLabz, if you're pointing out that the definition vs. the dereference are confusingly similar, you aren't wrong.  However, at least C doesn't seem like it's actively trying to trick you.  I always had to pick a careful subset of C++ and stick to that if I wanted to ensure that I'd have code that did what I expected it to.  "How many places can we put the const keyword on a single line...?"

Answer (score 4):

When you say `*param1` you are dereferencing the pointer. So if `param1` is a pointer to an integer `1`, you are essentially saying `func1(1)`.

When you say `&param2` you are passing the address of `param2` to the function. So basically you are passing a pointer to `param2`.

Answer (score 4):

`*` is the dereference operator *in this context*, while `&` is the reference operator. For example, suppose you have two variables: `int *a` and `int b`. `a` is a pointer to some integer value, whereas b is itself an integer value. Then, for example:

```
func(a) // Pass a copy of a, which points to the same value as a.
func(*a) // Pass a copy of the value a points to.
func(b) // Pass a copy of b.
func(&b) // Pass a pointer which points to b.
```

One extra note is that the C & operator is **not to be confused with**, in C++, when a function is defined as: `void func(const std::string &s)` - in C, there are no "references" like there are in C++, only pointers and values.

As for the advantage of one way over the other, I wouldn't really say there is one. It just depends on what you need your function to do. Suppose you wanted to create a function called modifyNumber() which accepted some integer and changed it - and you wanted that change to be visible by the caller.

Whenever values are passed to functions in C, they are **copied** - this means that, if you defined your modifyNumber() function like this:

```
modifyNumber(int i)
{
    i = 5;
}
```

It would change the value of `i`, but only **its copy of `i`**. If you want the code that called the function to also see the change, you would need to do something like this:

```
modifyNumber(int *i)
{
    *i = 5;
}

// Elsewhere in the code...

int i = 1;
modifyNumber(&i);
// Now i == 5.
```

In this case, you are passing a **pointer to your variable `i`**, which gets copied - but that's okay, because it's still pointing to **the same value**. So when we change the **value** with the dereference operator, the value is changed "globally" in a sense - so anyone with a pointer to the same value will see the change as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is fundamental C.

- `*` *dereferences* a pointer, going to the memory address stored in a pointer and evaluating the memory there based on the pointer's declared type.  For example: a pointer to an int, when dereferenced, will provide an integer value.
- `&` *retrieves* the memory address that a variable is stored at.  This address can be stored in a pointer variable.